# Joining tables using variable columns - dplyr, r, join

Tags: r, join, dplyr

**Problem:**  I have 2 tables I'd like to join.  However, the column upon which I wish to join the second to the first will vary dependent upon a successful parsing of the 2nd data frame to identify which column and row to join.

**Request:**  I have found a solution to the problem (see below) but it does not seem to me to very computationally efficient.  Not a problem for the reproducible example below but potentially less ideal when stepped out to a larger scale problem i.e. ~200,000+ rows / observations.

Wondering if anyone might be able to help identify something better - ideally utilising functionality from dplyr.

**Reproducible Example:**

```
# Equipment alias table
alias1    <- c('a1a1', 'a2a2', 'a3a3', 'a4a4', 'a5a5', 'a6a6')
alias2   <- c('bc001', 'bc002', 'bc003', 'bc004', 'bc005', 'bc006')
alias3   <- c('e1o1', 'e202', 'e303', 'e404', 'e505', 'e606')

df_alias <- data.frame(alias1, alias2, alias3)

# Attribute table
equip    <- c('a1a1','bc006', 'e404')
att1     <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
att2     <- c('1', '2', '3')

df_att   <- data.frame(equip, att1, att2)
```

**Desired Outcome:**

I'm looking to achieve the following....

```
# DESRIED OUTPUT - combining equipment alias table into attribute table based on string match between attibute_equip and any one of columns in equipment alias
equip    <- c('a1a1','bc006', 'e404')
att1     <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
att2     <- c('1', '2', '3')
alias1   <- c('a1a1','a6a6', 'a4a4')
alias2   <- c('bc001','bc006', 'bc004')
alias3   <- c('e1o1','e606', 'e404')

df_att   <- data.frame(equip, att1, att2, alias1, alias2, alias3)
```

**Current Solution:**

```
library(dplyr)  
left_join(df_att, df_alias, by = character()) %>% 
filter(equip == alias1 | equip == alias2 | equip == alias3)
```

Effective but not exactly elegant as there's a great deal of duplication for ultimately a filter to then be applied to undo that duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to `filter` with `if_any` and then bind the subset rows with the `df_att`

```
library(dplyr)
df_att2 <- df_alias %>%
    filter(if_any(everything(), ~ .x %in% df_att$equip)) %>% 
    arrange(na.omit(unlist(across(everything(), ~ match(df_att$equip, .x))))) %>% 
    bind_cols(df_att, .)
```

-checking with OP's expected (changed the object name 'df_att' to 'out' to avoid any confusion)

```
> all.equal(df_att2, out)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Makes absolute sense to make the filter and then the join!  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it compares efficiency-wise, but one idea is to pivot a copy of each alias so that you can `left_join` against a single column instead of multiple ones.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df_alias %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~., .names = "_{.col}")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with('_'), names_to = NULL, values_to = 'equip') %>% 
  left_join(df_att, .)

#> Joining, by = "equip"
#>   equip att1 att2 alias1 alias2 alias3
#> 1  a1a1    a    1   a1a1  bc001   e1o1
#> 2 bc006    b    2   a6a6  bc006   e606
#> 3  e404    c    3   a4a4  bc004   e404
```

Comment: Working it through I would say more efficient than my initial solution due to the fact that I had significant replication.  This obviously contains some but is vastly reduced.  I shall test against a larger dataset in the morning to see how things compare (timing the the execution - more for interest).  Thank you for your help!